# Cypress or Puppeteer: How to test page with a react select popup/popover?

Tags: puppeteer, cypress, react-select

**Request:**
Either with Cypress (preferably) or using extending Cypress with Puppeteer via `cy.task()`, being able to perform a test on a system-generated popup menu?

This popup menu element cannot be inspected by Chrome Devtools and is thereby not navigatable by either CSS selectors or XPath.

**Details:** I am using **Cypress** for UX testing and extend in limited cases with custom `cy.task()` with **Puppeteer**.

The web page under test has a dropdown selection that generates a popup menu, source is this npm module:
[npm react-select-async-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-async-paginate)

[image: popup menu]

Under inspections, the popup menu is generated from an  and it has these two attributes:

- [aria-haspopup="true"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-haspopup)
- [role="combobox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/combobox_role)

[image: element generating popup]

Appreciate assistance, thank you

---

**22 Feb, Updated**

This is the generated **react-select-async-paginate**:

```
<div>
  <div class="***-singleValue">Offer Letter w/ Signature</div>
  <div class=" css-ackcql" data-value="">
    <input 
        id="react-select-2-input" 
        aria-autocomplete="list" 
        aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-controls="react-select-2-listbox" 
        aria-owns="react-select-2-listbox" 
        role="combobox">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the attempt for selecting an option, but it does not loads selected option into `<div class="***-singleValue">`.

This Cypress script selects an option:

```
  cy.get(`${selectorReactSelectPaginate}`)
    .find('input[role="combobox"]')
    .focus()
    .type($valueSelect, { force: true })
    .then(() => {
      cy.wrap(true);
    });
```

As would able to validated using this Cypress script:

```
  cy.get(selectorReactSelectPaginate)
    .find('div[class*="-singleValue"]')
    .contains($valueSelectContains)
    .then(() => {
      cy.wrap(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the option list is tricky to get at in devtools because of the blur event (which comes from the library itself). One approach is open devtools and watch carefully as you click open the select.

Using [react-select-async-paginate - Simple Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o75rno2w65), when I click open the select I can see this div appearing and disappearing

```js
<div id="react-select-2-listbox">
```

So I can use Cypress to get a look inside that

```js
cy.get('[role="combobox"]').click()

cy.get('#react-select-2-listbox')
  .then($listbox => {
    console.log($listbox)
  })
```

Now in devtools console, check out `children` property (has one child), then the child's children - these look like the options to be tested.

The common selector is an id starting with `react-select-2-option`, so I can test like so

```js
cy.get('[role="combobox"]').click()

cy.get('#react-select-2-listbox')
  .find('[id^="react-select-2-option"]')   // all div's with id starting react-select-2-option
  .should('have.length', 10)
  .eq(3)                      // check out the 4th option
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', 'Option 4')   // passes
```

---

**Selecting an option by typing into the box**

Two things affect this method of selecting

- the dropdown list changes (reloads) as you type characters
- the element `'div[class*="-singleValue"]'` only appears after you confirm the typed value (either enter key or blur(), I'm not sure which).

This worked for me

```js
// Type in the option
cy.get(selectorReactSelectPaginate)
  .find('[role="combobox"]')
  .type(valueToSelect)

// Wait for the listbox to respond
cy.get('#react-select-2-listbox')
  .should('contain', valueToSelect)  

// Blur or enter will set the value
cy.get(selectorReactSelectPaginate)
  .find('[role="combobox"]')
  .type('{enter}')
  .blur()

// Check the value
cy.get(selectorReactSelectPaginate)
  .find('div[class*="-singleValue"]')
  .should('contain', valueToSelect)
```

Comment: I have updated the question with code presenting an attempt to select an option within `react-select-paginate-async`, but it fails.

Comment: I added a section that uses typing in the option instead of clicking on the option list item. Also requires some special handling.

Answer (score 2):

A neat trick with test runner is to add a `.wait()` after the dropdown selection appears. A snapshot of the DOM will be created and you can click on the `.wait()` to view the snapshot and use dev tools to inspect the dropdown selection.

Comment: Do you mean `.pause()`?

Comment: No. It's easier to get a snapshot with `.wait()`. I've been using it for certain suggestion pop ups in my app and dropdowns.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it is generally helpful (used with a wait time of course e.g `cy.wait(1000)`). In this case the options are quite fleeting and disappear as soon as they lose focus. When you say "snapshot", are you referring to a jpg or to the time-travel feature?

Comment: Its the time travel feature. So when you click on the `.wait(1000)` step you can inspect the element that typically disappears on blur

Comment: I have updated the question with code presenting an attempt to select an option within react-select-paginate-async, but it fails.