# How to get this element from an email type input with Cypress

Tags: javascript, popup, cypress, tooltip

I need to validate the message that the user receives when entering an invalid email (without using @, for example) but the element does not exist in the DOM tree and so far I have not found any way to get this text.

Element to be caught

[image: 1]

So far I've tried to treat the "alert" as a tooltip or popup but in no way that I found on the internet could I get this value

Comment: Check this answer out with getting a dom snapshot so you can view it with time travel feature. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71152206/17917809

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS pseudo class for that. Below I'm giving one blog read from Gleb which highlight different techniques for HTML form validation:

Your code will be look more or less similar to this after that:

```
cy.get('#form-validation').within(() => {
      cy.get('#email').invoke('prop', 'validationMessage')
        .should('equal', 'YOUR TEXT IN THE ERROR MESSAGE...')
}
```

Gleb's Blog: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/form-validation-in-cypress/